# Rails server startup errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, sass, rubygems

When i startup the server i get these errors:

/home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootstrap-4.1.3/lib/bootstrap/version.rb:2: warning: already initialized constant Bootstrap::VERSION
/home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/lib/bootstrap-sass/version.rb:2: warning: previous definition of VERSION was here
/home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootstrap-4.1.3/lib/bootstrap/version.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant Bootstrap::BOOTSTRAP_SHA
/home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/lib/bootstrap-sass/version.rb:3: warning: previous definition of BOOTSTRAP_SHA was here

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.4.4'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.0'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'bootstrap'
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 4.7'
gem 'sass-rails'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'devise'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'byebug'
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'sidekiq-failures', '~> 1.0'
gem 'pg_search'
gem 'faker'
gem 'select2-rails'
gem 'underscore-rails'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'money-rails'
gem 'stripe'
gem 'figaro'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15', '< 4.0'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]


    GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (5.2.1)
      actionpack (= 5.2.1)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailer (5.2.1)
      actionpack (= 5.2.1)
      actionview (= 5.2.1)
      activejob (= 5.2.1)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (5.2.1)
      actionview (= 5.2.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.1)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (5.2.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
    activejob (5.2.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.1)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (5.2.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.1)
    activerecord (5.2.1)
      activemodel (= 5.2.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.1)
      arel (>= 9.0)
    activestorage (5.2.1)
      actionpack (= 5.2.1)
      activerecord (= 5.2.1)
      marcel (~> 0.3.1)
    activesupport (5.2.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.5.2)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 4.0)
    archive-zip (0.11.0)
      io-like (~> 0.3.0)
    arel (9.0.0)
    autoprefixer-rails (9.1.4)
      execjs
    bcrypt (3.1.12)
    bindex (0.5.0)
    bootsnap (1.3.2)
      msgpack (~> 1.0)
    bootstrap (4.1.3)
      autoprefixer-rails (>= 6.0.3)
      popper_js (>= 1.12.9, < 2)
      sass (>= 3.5.2)
    bootstrap-sass (3.3.7)
      autoprefixer-rails (>= 5.2.1)
      sass (>= 3.3.4)
    builder (3.2.3)
    byebug (10.0.2)
    capybara (3.7.2)
      addressable
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
      rack (>= 1.6.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      xpath (~> 3.1)
    childprocess (0.9.0)
      ffi (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.11)
    chromedriver-helper (2.0.1)
      archive-zip (~> 0.10)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
    coffee-rails (4.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.5)
    connection_pool (2.2.2)
    crass (1.0.4)
    devise (4.5.0)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 4.1.0, < 6.0)
      responders
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    erubi (1.7.1)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    faker (1.8.7)
      i18n (>= 0.7)
    faraday (0.15.2)
      multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
    ffi (1.9.25)
    figaro (1.1.1)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    font-awesome-sass (4.7.0)
      sass (>= 3.2)
    globalid (0.4.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    i18n (1.0.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    io-like (0.3.0)
    jbuilder (2.7.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.3.3)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    listen (3.1.5)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
      ruby_dep (~> 1.2)
    loofah (2.2.2)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.0)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    marcel (0.3.3)
      mimemagic (~> 0.3.2)
    method_source (0.9.0)
    mimemagic (0.3.2)
    mini_mime (1.0.1)
    mini_portile2 (2.3.0)
    minitest (5.11.3)
    monetize (1.9.0)
      money (~> 6.12)
    money (6.12.0)
      i18n (>= 0.6.4, < 1.1)
    money-rails (1.12.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      monetize (~> 1.9.0)
      money (~> 6.12.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
    msgpack (1.2.4)
    multi_json (1.13.1)
    multipart-post (2.0.0)
    nio4r (2.3.1)
    nokogiri (1.8.4)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.3.0)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    pg (0.21.0)
    pg_search (2.1.2)
      activerecord (>= 4.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
      arel (>= 6)
    popper_js (1.14.3)
    public_suffix (3.0.3)
    puma (3.12.0)
    rack (2.0.5)
    rack-protection (2.0.4)
      rack
    rack-test (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (5.2.1)
      actioncable (= 5.2.1)
      actionmailer (= 5.2.1)
      actionpack (= 5.2.1)
      actionview (= 5.2.1)
      activejob (= 5.2.1)
      activemodel (= 5.2.1)
      activerecord (= 5.2.1)
      activestorage (= 5.2.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.1)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 5.2.1)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.4)
      loofah (~> 2.2, >= 2.2.2)
    railties (5.2.1)
      actionpack (= 5.2.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.1)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.19.0, < 2.0)
    rake (12.3.1)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.3)
    rb-inotify (0.9.10)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0, < 2)
    redis (4.0.2)
    responders (2.4.0)
      actionpack (>= 4.2.0, < 5.3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0, < 5.3)
    ruby_dep (1.5.0)
    rubyzip (1.2.2)
    sass (3.5.7)
      sass-listen (~> 4.0.0)
    sass-listen (4.0.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    sass-rails (5.0.7)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 6)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    select2-rails (4.0.3)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    selenium-webdriver (3.14.0)
      childprocess (~> 0.5)
      rubyzip (~> 1.2)
    sidekiq (5.2.2)
      connection_pool (~> 2.2, >= 2.2.2)
      rack-protection (>= 1.5.0)
      redis (>= 3.3.5, < 5)
    sidekiq-failures (1.0.0)
      sidekiq (>= 4.0.0)
    simple_form (4.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 5.0)
      activemodel (>= 5.0)
    spring (2.0.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      spring (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
    sprockets (3.7.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    stripe (3.26.1)
      faraday (~> 0.10)
    thor (0.20.0)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.0.8)
    turbolinks (5.2.0)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5.2)
    turbolinks-source (5.2.0)
    tzinfo (1.2.5)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (4.1.19)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    underscore-rails (1.8.3)
    warden (1.2.7)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    web-console (3.7.0)
      actionview (>= 5.0)
      activemodel (>= 5.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    websocket-driver (0.7.0)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.3)
    xpath (3.1.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  autoprefixer-rails
  bootsnap (>= 1.1.0)
  bootstrap
  bootstrap-sass
  byebug
  capybara (>= 2.15, < 4.0)
  chromedriver-helper
  coffee-rails (~> 4.2)
  devise
  faker
  figaro
  font-awesome-sass (~> 4.7)
  jbuilder (~> 2.5)
  jquery-rails
  listen (>= 3.0.5, < 3.2)
  money-rails
  pg
  pg_search
  puma (~> 3.11)
  rails (~> 5.2.0)
  sass-rails
  select2-rails
  selenium-webdriver
  sidekiq
  sidekiq-failures (~> 1.0)
  simple_form
  spring
  spring-watcher-listen (~> 2.0.0)
  stripe
  turbolinks (~> 5)
  tzinfo-data
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  underscore-rails
  web-console (>= 3.3.0)

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.4.4p296

BUNDLED WITH
   1.16.3
```

Answer (score 5):

If you read the errors it's telling you that `bootstrap` and `bootstrap-sass` are conflicting. Why are you using both?

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'bootstrap'
```

Try just deleting the line `gem 'bootstrap'` and run `bundle`. The `bootstrap-sass` gem is a SASS ready version of bootstrap so you only want one or the other. Also the latest `bootstrap` gem is for Bootstrap 4, the `bootstrap-sass` gem is for Bootstrap 3 or 2. So depending which version of Bootstrap you want, pick the appropriate gem.

Comment: @LuisCarlosQuarta When an answer solves your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks.